# How to get Featured products display using attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, featured-product

I want to create featured products attribute for that I created an attribute and selected catalog input type as yes/no and then selected used for sorting in product listing but the featured products are not being displayed instead all the products are being displayed

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here I can recommend using an extension.

I have used in the past this [extension](http://amasty.com/improved-sorting.html), and it is working great But it is not free. 
but Also not more so expensive.

Also you can add sorting by best sellers,rating and any of your custom attribute you can add with this extension from admin configuration, it has really nice sorting options in catalog grid and list view.

hope this will sure help you.

i am not promoting any extension or associated with this link. Its just for your help